# How do I keyframe transform and rotation values whilst moving and object on a path using 'Follow path' contraint

Tags: camera, keyframes, constraints, path

thank you in advance

I've been banging my head for the last week trying to solve this issue. I need to export my files in a specific way and require my NLA animations made a specific way as im using my gltf file within a web framework.

I am aware that we can create keyframes and move cameras on paths and capture keyframe values of the offset, but how do I record keyframes for transform and rotation properties? when I keyframe said properties, no values are recorded as these do not change whilst the object is constrained to the path.

I have tried everything I know of and cant manage to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty, set a copy loc constraint on the camera targeting the empty, set a copy rot using "Add" mix instead of default "replace", set the empty to follow the curve path.

When everything works as expected, select the camera, in the 3D window, object mode, go to Object menu, choose animation, bake action, enabling the preferences in the image below.

Now you can delete the curve and the empty, animation is baked as camera keyframes.

[image]

Comment: Josh is right, BUT if you are a beginner ...and i assume you are, i think, his "explanation" is more for advanced users and difficult to realize for beginner. So if you need a "step by step"-explanation, just let us know.

Comment: Wow this is a quick community Thank you so much. I am new. I am going to try my best to follow Josh's explanation and come back if I need further help. 

Thank you so much!